# Is there an easy way to turn empty form inputs into null strings in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, form-submit

I'm using Spring MVC and *SimpleJdbcInsert* to insert objects into a MySQL database. I'd like to set the blank input to `NULL` in the database rather than `''`.  I have quite a few fields, and I'm hoping for a way to do this without manually checking every value.

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

So I'm an idiot.  Several errors combined on my part led me to believe the correct answers below were not correct. I'd written a *PropertyEditorSupport* like this:

```
class StringEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public void setAsText(String text) {
        String value = text.trim();
        if ("" == value) {
            setValue(null);  
        } else {  
            setValue(value);  
        }
    }

}
```

There are two problems:

1. no getAsText, so my form was getting populated with "null" strings!
2. my equality check is C++, not Java.  When I tried the recommended
   setter, I just reloaded the post, which already contained the "null"
   strings. Once I cleaned all that up, everything started working.

Thanks for the help, and sorry for my "operator error"!

Brett

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647214/form-values-to-be-null-instead-of-empty-strings-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The class you're looking for is:

```
org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor
```

If you construct it with a `true` it will convert empty/whitespace strings to null.  How to get it registered onto the binder depends on if you want it to be the default or only apply to certain views.

e.g., on a single controller you can just add

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

[instructions here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)

Comment: See my comments to Bozho regarding registerCustomEditor not working in Spring 2.5.5

Comment: Well, I can't swear on 2.5.5, but I am quite sure on 2.5.6 and 3 that it sets the string to the null reference, it doesn't set a string with a value of "null."  Perhaps if you added the offending code to your question we could help more?

Comment: See my edit to the original post.  My bad, thanks for your patience.

Comment: Just a warning: `@InitBinder` can only configure binding of `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameters. It is useless for `@RequestBody` annotated parameters.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is old, but I wasted about 2 or 3 hours until I found a very easy way to apply a `StringTrimmerEditor` with a binder for all my controllers.

Once again: I must remember to RTFM.

In spring 3.2 you can create a `@ControllerAdvice`-annottated controller class and use the `@InitBinder`-annotated method just like the example @Affe gave.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder-advice

Here is an example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Controller
public class AppBindingInitializer {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }

}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Why do you need `@Controller` and `@ControllerAdvice` annotations both on the same bean?

Comment: I'm sorry. Don't remember now and couldn't find easily a reason in google. :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use a [custom Binder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)

Comment: I tried that, but it returns a String.  Trying setValue(null) left me with Strings == "null" (the four letter word "null", not the value null).  Not quite what I was looking for!

Comment: can't you return `null` String?

Comment: Custom binder is right.  Where you see this `Strings == "null"`; what are you doing?  Are you building a SQL string, if so DONT.  Use a Preprable.

Comment: Does this only work in older versions of Spring?  I'm using 2.5.5 and it isn't working, even using the StringTrimmerEditor also suggested.  The object I'm binding to is getting a String with the value of "null".  I can pass the object back to a new webpage and I will have the text "null", so this isn't related to SQL at all.  So I'm stuck thinking this only works for older versions of Spring.  what else could it be?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Set the default value for your optional fields to NULL - actually is it not NULL by default?</del>

Parse your input string and then explicitly specify only populated columns with

```
 usingColumns
```

oh, and I'd advise to always sanitise your inputs...

Comment: Mind telling me how to set the default value to NULL?  I'm getting empty strings back, so I'm guessing NULL isn't the default.

Comment: I think it's the default, but you can also add an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause to each field.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

NB - Note my strikethru - I read this initially outside the context of the SimpleJdbcInsert class

Comment: Ok, I have default NULL for the database. I thought you were refering to a way to set null as the default java String result for empty input on the form!  The problem with usingColumns (I think) is that it takes (String ...) as the arguments - I need to hardcode them, not create a list of string arguments dynamically at runtime by checking the values.  I could also have the getters return null for empty strings, which seems comparable, but again means checking every value.