# I want to validate an object conditionally

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

i have an object in my class. I validate it with hibernate validator like this:

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{1,13}")
private String onlyNumber = null;
```

But, i want to validate my object when

```
if(onlyNumber != null && !onlyNumber.equals("")
```

because it is optional.
And i want to do it with regular expression. Is there any way to succeed this?
thanks

Comment: You need to write your custom ConstraintValidator and Annotation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998978/how-to-use-pattern-on-non-mandatory-fields-jsr-303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]{0,13}")
```

should be sufficient. null values are always considered valid (you need `@NotNull` in addition to other validations to reject null). And the empty string matches the above regexp.

Comment: Yes you' re right but actually my string can get "" value and i want to reject validation in this case too.

Comment: Yes, so? Have you tried the above? As I said: the empty string matches the above regexp. So the empty string is a valid value. And that's what you want.

Comment: sorry, i thought it was the same as mine.
Yes it tried and it worked. Thank you !!