# Form values to be NULL instead of empty strings in Spring MVC

Tags: forms, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC. I have a form on my page. When I do not enter any values to the form and submit it, it comes with empty strings `""`.

Is it possible to set `null` value instead of empty strings?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to use the [@InitBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html) annotation because in Spring MVC it always returns `""` for the blank values in a form. You have to add this in your controller.

Example:

```
@InitBinder    /* Converts empty strings into null when a form is submitted */
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));  
}
```

[*Source*](http://www.bitspedia.com/2012/09/spring-mvc-31-how-to-convert-form-empty.html)

Comment: Great answer. I might add that you can also specify a single property you wish to register the custom editor for:

`binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "myproperty", new StringTrimmerEditor(true));`

Comment: Its fine. But i am facing problem when i send the ajax request to the controller. I know that @InitBinder doesn't work for ajax request. So, how can i resolve this issue.