# Spring form tags. Allow nulls in form:select (enum)

Tags: spring, jsp, enums, jstl

I'm using Spring form tags for filling form with values.

I have form backing object:

```
public class FormInfo {
  public enum Status {ON, OFF}

  private Satus status;
  //getter setter
  ...
}
```

And in JSP `Status` enum presented like this:

```
<form:form commandObject="formInfo " ...>
     <form:select path="status">
        <form:option value="null" label="Please select"/>
        <form:options/>
     </form:select>
</form:form>
```

All works fine, i.e. default message and enum values are presented in `<select>`.

But the status field is not required, so I want allow user to leave Status field unselected. But if form submitted without selecting status field, then I get error:

> error in object 'formInfo' on field 'status': rejected value [null];

**How I can set enum to null when no values is selected?**

Please note I'm using JSR 303 validation. And error described above is not happens automatically, I get this error message manually from following method `BindingResult#getFieldErrors()`.

This is my controller code:

```
    public void myMethod(@Valid @ModelAttribute("formInfo") FormInfo sourcingDetail, BindingResult bindingResult) {
          if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
              log.error("Error during validation is occurred." + bindingResult.getFieldErrors().toString()); // <-- this is error message
          }
        ...
    }
```

Also please note, I didn't set any JSR-303 annotation (like @NotNull) on `status` field.

**UPDATE:**

Almost full error message which I get from calling this method `BindingResult#getFieldErrors()` (explained above):

> Error during validation is occurred.[Field error in object 'formInfo'
>   on field 'status': rejected value [null];
>
> ...
>
> [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'com.my.project.model.Status' for property 'status';
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert
>   value of type [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [com.my.project.model.Status] for property 'status': no matching
>   editors or conversion strategy found],

Comment: Is this the full error? It does not look like a Bean Validation error. Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: @Hardy I updated question (added full error message and additional code to controller method). Please review it. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this is a conversion error. The frontend gives you a string as status, but you expect an emum type. As far as i ca tell nothing at all Bean Validation related. I am not sure how and if JSF can the conversion for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have the same problem as i!.

There is a method in the controller that serves as a hook where you could specify how to transform the String values, that came from the HTTP request, to a concrete object!.
The method is called initBinder, and there you attach the right behavior to do the conversion properly. I am still researching, but so far, looks good.

Take a look at this :

- [Form Values to be Null instead of "" in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647214/form-values-to-be-null-instead-of-in-spring)
- http://kaushalyas.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/data-binding-in-spring-mvc.html

Hope it helps to found the solution!

Greetings

Victor.

Comment: Also just discovered that the default binder for enum transform the "" to null, at least for Spring 2.5!