# How to set RequestMapping default/required value for URL?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

The following URL queries the DB and returns all values correctly using requestParam as below:

```
    http://localhost:8080/app/locateUser/search?firstname=John&lastname=Clay&id=2

    @RequestParam(value = "firstname") String firstname,
    @RequestParam(value = "lastname") String lastname,
    @RequestParam(value = "id" ) int id
```

Now I want to make lastname optional(remove from URL) in like this:

http://localhost:8080/app/locateUser/search?firstname=John&id=2

or

http://localhost:8080/app/locateUser/search?firstname=John&lastname=&id=2

How do I make the url optional?  I want to be able to query the DB without lastname in the URL string.

This is what I have:

```
    @RequestParam(value = "firstname") String firstname,
    @RequestParam(value = "lastname" defaultValue = "lname") String lastname,
    @RequestParam(value = "id" ) int id
```

I've also tried

```
   @RequestParam(value = "lastname" required=false) String lastname,
```

Neither seems to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: It should work with `required = false`, show us your complete method signature and the error you are having, it may help to understand your problem

Comment: What isn't working... When `required=false` then you get an empty string not null, you will of course have to do something further down the line to ignore empty params in the query...

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647214/form-values-to-be-null-instead-of-in-spring

Comment: i think this question is already done by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22373696/requestparam-in-spring-mvc-handling-optional-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In spring Request parameters are `required=true` by default. Also you should give other Request parameters required situations to specify.

You should make sure, did you deployed your latest war file. And also It seems you have a typo after `value` parameter you need to separate them with a `comma`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Turns out that the value/values with defaultValue must be last in the Param URL like this.  Everything works fine after that.  URL works if lastname is not present.  Thanks.

```
@RequestParam(value = "firstname") String firstname,
@RequestParam(value = "id" ) int id,
@RequestParam(value = "lastname" defaultValue = "lname") String lastname
```