# Set to NULL a Bound Form Field if Empty

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC, is it possible to set to NULL (rather than an empty string) a bound Form field?

If nothing is entered, my domain object field ends up blank. I need it to be set to NULL in this case.

```
<form:input path="myObject.department" />
```

Comment: I found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647214/form-values-to-be-null-instead-of-in-spring

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom editor for your strings that will transform empty strings into Null

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you; although this works, we have nested child elements, and only the "leaf" element gets set to NULL. The parent objects are created. In our case, if all children are NULL, the parent should also be NULL.