# Using InitBinder with command objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a command object that represents a form object submitted. If a value from a form input field is blank, I want it to be `null` in the command object.

I read a different [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977649/is-there-an-easy-way-to-turn-empty-java-spring-form-input-into-null-strings) that showed to use the `InitBinder`

I gave that a shot, but the `initBinder` method is never called.

My controller

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import com.example.MyDTO;

@Controller
public class MyControllerImpl implements MyController {

    @InitBinder("myControllerImpl")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        System.out.println("init binder");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }

    @Override
    public String someAction( MyDTO someDTO ) {

        System.out.println(someDTO);

        // Do something with DTO. I want blank values to be null here

        return "somePage;
    }

}
```

DTO

```
package com.example;

public class MyDTO {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public String setName() {

        return name;
    }

}
```

I also tried adding the class name to the `InitBinder` annotation

```
@InitBinder("myControllerImpl")
```

but it did not work.

What am I missing to get the init binder to be called?

I'm using Java 6 and Spring 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@ControllerAdvice` to controller class.

Comment: Missed that. Unfortunately, we're a bit outdated and using Spring 3.1.1 Not sure if I can upgrade to 3.2, most likely not. So this way probably won't work.

Comment: Should work. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#portlet-ann-initbinder

Comment: I have the InitBinder annotation, but it looks like @ControllerAdvice annotation wasn't added till 3.2

Comment: @eric as I wrote, docs says it should work as it is, dunno what is happening on your side

Comment: Looks like it is my interface causing the issue. When I removed the interface and added all of the @RequestMappings from the interface to the Impl, it worked. Not really sure why, but it's a starting place.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that I'm using an interface on my controller. The implementation is proxied by Spring AOP. To get this to work, I had to add the following method on the interface:

```
@InitBinder
void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder);
```

Then in the implementation I have

```
@Override
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    System.out.println("init binder!");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```