# In Spring MVC, how do I convert empty String properties of a @RequestBody object into null?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring `@RestController` that uses Jackson to deserialize JSON into a Spring `@RequestBody` object:

```
@PutMapping
public void save(@RequestBody Car car)
```

Car has a few properties and nested properties that are Strings. I would like to convert all empty Strings to null.

I found a few posts (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2977863/1706691)) indicating to use an `@InitBinder` but this doesn't work with `@RequestBody`. How can I do this using `@RequestBody`?

**Update**

Providing an example to hopefully clarify what I'd like to accomplish:

Suppose a client passes the following JSON that represents a `Car`:

```
{
   "name" : "  ",
   "vin" : "123ABC",
   "model" : {
            "name" : "240SX"
            "description" : ""
   }
}
```

(Other properties omitted for brevity.)

Then, my `save(@RequestBody Car car)` should receive this `Car` object but altered such that the following are true:

```
car.getName() == null
car.getVin().equals("123ABC")
car.getModel().getName().equals("240SX")
car.getModel().getDescription() == null
```

In general terms, any empty string should be converted into null. I want this behavior to be limited to this `save` controller method.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you can add a custom deserialization feature to Jackson to convert empty strings to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class CustomJacksonConfig implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializers(new JsonDeserializer<String>(){
            @Override
            public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JacksonException {
                return StringUtils.hasLength(p.getText()) ? p.getText() : null;
            }
            @Override
            public Class<String> handledType() {
                return String.class;
            }
        });
    }
}
```